# Exterior and interior bounds for 2D data plot

Tags: matlab, math, matlab-figure, computational-geometry

https://dropmefiles.com/kIe16 - this contains two matrices from Matlab

With the code below, I'm building the following plot:

```
n = 1:1:(51);
plot(Xm(n,:)',Rm(n,:)','b.','MarkerSize',8)
grid on
grid minor
```

[image]

What I need to do: build the exterior and interior bounds for this 2D data plot, like here. This is very approximate.

[image]

**My considerations:** I roughly understand how to build the upper and lower exterior boundaries. Since the data is divided into vertical lines, we can simply find their min and max, and then connect them with straight lines. But I have absolutely no ideas about interior boundaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is contour-from-image extraction problem.

There is well-known Suzuki algorithm to extract whole hierarchy of contours from bw images.

Suzuki, S. and Abe, K., Topological Structural Analysis of Digitized Binary Images by Border Following. CVGIP 30 1, pp 32-46 (1985).

It is implemented in the OpenCV library (I used it from C++ and Python), and looks like it is accessible/available from MATLAB, https://www.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-opencv.html

Comment: MATLAB has the same contour extraction algorithm, no need for involving OpenCV. https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwboundaries.html

Comment: @CrisLuengo From description looks like it is a different algorithm , but if it works, one might try it first

Comment: @CrisLuengo do I understand correctly that first I need to replace all NaN with zeros, and all other numbers with ones?

Comment: @dtn I haven’t looked at your data. I assume you have integer (x,y) coordinates for your points. Create a zeros array of appropriate size, then set the pixel for each point to 1. Now run the contour tracing algorithm.

Comment: @CrisLuengo i have arrays with real decimal numbers

Comment: @dtn But they're in a grid, you can scale to make the grid points integers.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I was able to adapt your recommendation to my needs. The "bwboundaries" algorithm seems to work. And this is a very interesting algorithm. I would like to understand its essence. What source can I turn to?

Comment: @dtn try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_neighborhood

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux thank you very much! very inspiring information

Answer (score 1):

**1.-** Use `diff(..,1,1)` and `diff(..,1,2)` to obtain 1st derivatives along `x` and along `y` respectively.

`diff(..,1,1)` is 1st derivative along `x` axis and `diff(..,1,2)` is 1st derivative along `y` axis.

Display origin is located on top left corner and `y` increases downwards.

**2.-** The obtained 2D 1st derivative shows the points where the shape starts and stops, for each row and column, including the inner gaps.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I have used the `diff` function once and it really helps to define and plot "borders and voids" edge points on a plot. But I can't figure out yet how determine what class they belong to (borders or interior) and connect them accordingly. `idx = all(isnan(Rm(:,n)),2); idr = diff(find([1;diff(idx);1])); D = mat2cell(Rm(:,1),idr(:),size(Rm(:,1),2)); D{1:2:end}; Dmax=cellfun(@max,D);
Dmin=cellfun(@min,D); bounds = [Dmin;Dmax]; bounds = bounds(~isnan(bounds)); bounds = [unique(Xm(:,1))*ones(size(bounds,1),1),bounds]; plot(bounds(:,1),bounds(:,2),'ro','MarkerSize',8)`

Comment: for each line sweep, either along x or y, you have to count pulses produced by abs(diff(..,1,1)) and abs(diff(:,1,2)) : ..1..1.. is exterior border. ..1..1..1..1.. is 1st and 4th exterior border and 2nd 3rd interior so on so forth. Build a switch with all the options. Don't leave behind the odd counts : ..1.. is just the tip of an exterior border.  ..1..1..1.. is 1st and 3rd exterior border and the middle one is the tip of an interior border. Put a ceiling to how many interior borders you can detect.

Comment: Another way : Your data has a grid spacing of 0.02 . Any larger spacing between adjacent numbers is an inner gap or bubble.

Comment: I think that an interesting algorithm can also be built on your proposals. The "gap" idea is simple, but can be very useful. I'll try to work on this in my spare time. Thank you!